# Collapsing whitespace with Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

First, here's a screenshot of the issue I am talking about:

[image]

I am trying to make the whitespace disappear. For example, I would like the 4th comment ('comment comment comment') to be under the first comment without a large gap between them, instead of skipping that column and being in the second column.

Basically, I want 3 columns of these Bootstrap wells which don't care about the height of the other columns' comments. I've tried using clearfix, but I don't exactly understand if that is correct in this situation (and I couldn't get it to work regardless).

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="row comment-container">
    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="comment in comments">              
      <div class="well">
        <span><button type="button" class="close" ng-click="deleteComment(comment)" ng-show="isAdmin()">&times;</button></span>
        {{comment.text}}
        <br>
        <br>
        <p class='text-right'>-{{comment.name}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <form class="comment-form col-sm-8">
        <label>Leave your comment here!</label>
        <p class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="comment-input form-control" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="newComment.name" ng-hide="isLoggedIn()">
          <input type="text" class="comment-input form-control" placeholder="Your comment" ng-model="newComment.text">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary comment-button" ng-click="addComment()">Comment</button>
        </p>
      </form>
  </div>


</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of what I would like it to look like (this example illustrates the issue with not calculating the height of the comments and using a simple %3 comparison on a modified version of crazymatt's code.

http://i7.minus.com/j6idHIfytxl1w.PNG

This was generated with:

```
<div class="comment-container">
      <div class="col-md-4">            
        <div class="well" ng-repeat="comment in comments" ng-if="($index) % 3 === 0">
            <span><button type="button" class="close" ng-click="deleteComment(comment)" ng-show="isAdmin()">&times;</button></span>
          {{comment.text}}
          <br>
          <br>
          <p class='text-right'>-{{comment.name}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">            
        <div class="well" ng-repeat="comment in comments" ng-if="($index) % 3 === 1">
          <span><button type="button" class="close" ng-click="deleteComment(comment)" ng-show="isAdmin()">&times;</button></span>
          {{comment.text}}
          <br>
          <br>
          <p class='text-right'>-{{comment.name}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">            
        <div class="well" ng-repeat="comment in comments" ng-if="($index) % 3 === 2">
          <span><button type="button" class="close" ng-click="deleteComment(comment)" ng-show="isAdmin()">&times;</button></span>
          {{comment.text}}
          <br>
          <br>
          <p class='text-right'>-{{comment.name}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this is not your code by any means

Comment: This is modified from a yeoman code generator. So no, I didn't create all of this code from scratch. I'm not really sure why that's relevant though...

Comment: I meant this not the code for that part in your image, hence why I had to re-create it, and this is why it is relevant, this is code for something else totally unrelated to the question and to your image

Comment: Ah, sorry for the misunderstanding. The form is of course not part of the code displayed, but the <div class="row comment-container"> is the beginning of the definition of the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, while the common approach for this would be to set a `min-height` for your col-.... , this approach requires to have some knowledge of the height. Another approaches involve using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or getting the measures using jQuery. But here you have something I have been working for Bootstrap templates that fits your situation like a glove:}

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row myComments">

  <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">askljdsahj kasjdka sdkjasd klasjd adjalk jdklajsdklasjd klajsdkajsd jakljdsklasjd asjfkajslf vcsjdhfjs cbsjkghda bcsahdfga schjsagfhj acjgahjsgfdhja scjhgashjgf jahcjhgashjgfda hjsgj hagshjdga </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">6</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">7</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">9</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

(note that you added some random code to your question, so I built some code based on your image. Adjust as needed)

CSS goes as follows:

```
.myComments{display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;   
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
   -webkit-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row;
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
.col-md-4{ padding:10px; min-height:100%; width:33.3%;}
```

You can play with [Bootply code here](http://www.bootply.com/vsLPZmD0pe)

Comment: This is a good solution, but unfortunately not what I meant. This will not collapse the columns, but it will align them and force 3 objects into each row, which is certainly an improvement.

Comment: On further thought, it seems like the only way to do what I want would involve computing height to balance the 3 columns.

Comment: no, the 3 columns is not given by my code, but your md-4, that's Bootstrap behavior. What this code does is provide same height for all boxes no matter what, and has the ability to react in different ways based on responsive behaviors. Resize your window and you will see

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm having a difficult time communicating what I mean to you. The end result I was hoping for was like this image: !http://i7.minus.com/j6idHIfytxl1w.PNG

Comment: then, as I mentioned before, you need Masonry. Or if you want just CSS, try this new Bootply at http://www.bootply.com/HL8tSNOzqx with a different approach, which means getting rid of Bootstrap columns for that section (not a big issue either).

Comment: I did end up going with a masonry type solution, specifically this [angular module implementation](https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Based off the small amount of code you provided I think you may have your bootstrap rows and columns mixed up. For a three column layout in bootstrap you need to use a method like this

```
<div class="comment-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
          First comment data goes here...
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
          Second comment data goes here...
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
          Third comment data goes here...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
          Forth comment data goes here...
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
          Fifth comment data goes here...
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
          Sixth comment data goes here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can read through the documentation and examples on the [Bootstap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) website.

Comment: Couple this with ng-repeat and ng-if and this is a complete solution.

Comment: I think this is the closest to what I wanted to do, though I don't really like the idea of iterating over my list of comments 3 times (even though in practice it wouldn't matter for runtimes). My version of the code based on MBielski's suggestions is posted on the top.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `clearfix visible-xx` where 'xx' is the viewport size according to Bootstrap 3. According to your screenshot you will need to place a `<span class="clearfix visible-xx"></span>` element after every 3rd column. Please note here `'-xx'` can be `'-xs'` or `'-sm'` or `'-md'` based on the break point you want them to fix.

Here is a link with examples and explanation:

- [Clearing Bootstrap 3 columns](http://www.bluthemes.com/blog/3/clearing-bootstrap-3-columns)